# Scale Each Child View in Order

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to scale each view of a linearlayout in order. I am using the following animation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:duration="600"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

And applying it in this way

```
AnimationSet animationSet = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.scale)
LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController = new LayoutAnimationController(animationSet, 1f);
        segmentLinearLayout.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
        segmentLinearLayout.startLayoutAnimation();
```

The problem is that all child views are scaled up together and than 1 by 1 scaled down with no animation. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It is because both scales are starting and ending together

you can use `android:startOffset="600"` to start after 600 ms.

For example:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="600"
    android:toXScale="1.2"
    android:toYScale="1.2" />

<scale
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="600"
    android:duration="600"
    android:toXScale="0.83"
    android:toYScale="0.83" />
```

The 1st scale will take 600 ms and the second will start after 600 ms and then will take alone another 600 ms

Hope this helped !!

**Edit:**

2 edits:

1. I changed the `fromScale` and `toScale` in the second scale to `1` and `0.83` respectively so it returns to its original scale size because after the view is changed to its newer scale, the new 1 or 100% needs to return to 83% of its new scale (1/0.83 = 1.2)
2. Like you mentioned, the delay of the `LayoutAnimationController` also need to change. In the sample code that I've tried, I used `new LayoutAnimationController(animationSet, 2.0f)` to take 200% delay (600ms * 2 = 1200ms to rescale down)

Comment: unfortunately  the problem still exists the animations are out of sync

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to know what are you referring to. I tried it on a sample code and it worked perfectly !!

Comment: perhaps I have a problem with the delay that is set when instantiating the layoutAnimationController. What delay did you set in your sample code?

Comment: I misunderstood you the first time. Check my edit, I changed to 2 things. Hope that's what you're looking for !!